# how can apache run multiple applications on same server with different path

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, url

When i ssh to amazon ec2, then

```
pwd
/home/ubuntu


ls
app_1 app_2 app_3 app_4
```

Considering i have mapped my ec2-***-***-***-**  address to some apps.site1.com

How can i have multiple rails applications running like if i access,

```
apps.site1.com/app_1 apps.site1.com/app_2 apps.site1.com/app_3
```

each of the application should be loaded.

One of my friends told he has implemented it for apache+php application, where various index.php files are
present and each folder structure is independently available as separate running application.

How can i implement this for rails applications,

Comment: so i have achieved using RailsbaseURI, change apache.conf and default-ssl files and create a symlink to point to public folder of rails application.